# scheme - How do i explain an output like this?

Tags: stream, scheme, racket, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci

So I have been given the following definitions:

```
(define head car)

(define (tail stream) (force (cdr stream)))

(define (addL x  y)(cons-stream (+   (head x)   (head y))(addL (tail x)   (tail y))))

(define fibs(cons-stream 1(cons-stream 1
    (addL (tail fibs) fibs))))

(define (reorder order-stream data-stream)
   (cond ((stream-null? order-stream) the-empty-stream)
        ((stream-null? data-stream) the-empty-stream)
        (else (cons-stream (stream-ref data-stream (stream-first order-stream))
                (reorder (stream-rest order-stream) data-stream)))))
```

And i have been asked to display the first 7 numbers (which i will show below) and explain those numbers that are output from this line of code:

```
(reorder (tail fibs) (tail fibs))
```

The output of the first 7 elements of the resulting stream is:

"2, 3, 5, 13, 55, 610, 28657"

Does anyone have any idea for an explanation of this? I don't quite understand what's actually happening here...

Comment: Print the first 13 elements of `(tail fibs)`. See if you can find any correspondence between the elements and their positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `fibs` is the infinite (lazy) stream of the Fibonacci numbers,

```
fibs  = 1 , ft ...
ft    = 1 , (addL fibs ft) ...
; 1, 1, 2,  3,  5,  8,  13, ....
```

Allow me to write down the definition for `reorder` in a pseudocode, so it is easier to follow, as

```
(reorder js xs) = empty                         | if (empty? js) or (empty? xs)
                = xs[js[0]] , 
                   (reorder (rest js) xs) ...   | otherwise
```

Note that `xs` is passed along unchanged, and `js` is taken its head element from on each iteration. This means that `(reorder (stream i j k ... n ...) xs)` progressively takes the *i*th, then *j*th, *k*th, ... *n*th, ... elements from the  stream `xs`.

Since the call is `(reorder ft ft)`, the produced sequence is

```
ft[ft[0]], ft[ft[1]], ft[ft[2]], ...
```

i.e.

```
ft[1], ft[2], ft[3], ft[5], ft[8], ft[13], ....
```

which is what you see.